# What is the right way to make a consistent Amazon EBS snapshot with the SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I'm a new to Amazon Web Services (AWS) and want to create an [Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) snapshot with the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).
I wrote the following code:

```
    $aws = Aws::factory($config);
    $ec2 = $aws->get('Ec2');    
    $ec2->createSnapshot( array('VolumeId'=>'vol-11c22825','Description'=>'My Description') );
```

The snapshot is created correctly , but I'm concerned about data integrity.
Is there a better way to create a consistent snapshot with the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be completely consistent you need to freeze the filesystem. This can be done if you are running the script locally but you might need to issue a command via ssh if running remotely.

You might be interested in this: https://github.com/alestic/ec2-consistent-snapshot